# Android, Pick & Crop image using single startActivityForResult, but retrieving original image URI?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, crop

some time ago I managed to make the following code work (thanks to people on the Internet like you, definitely NOT the android documentation...).
What it basically does is start the file pick activity (in this case an image) and then jump right to the image crop activity, it then saves the cropped image to the provided file stream.

```
    File file = new File(saveTo);
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fs.close();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", maxImageSize);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", maxImageSize);
    intent.putExtra("scale", "true");
    //intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", !false);
    intent.putExtra("setWallpaper", false);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
```

First of all, **I'd like to make it clear that this works perfectly and I'm not having any problems with this code.**

The above code doesn't return any data in its intent. This is because "return-data" extra is commented out by purpose, so that the cropped image is saved directly to the open stream instead of hogging device memory and to prevent ugly behavior with large images.

*What I'd like to know is:*
**How can I get the URI of the ORIGINAL file** (*not the created file\thumbnail*) that was chosen and then cropped?
Is there a way of doing this without taking apart working code and trying to do this in several steps? (Like first picking the image and then running the cropping activity, storing the original file URI in between)

Comment: The only data it ever returns is inline data of bitmap. So the only way I see is to store file uri at local variable and retrieve when you are need.

Comment: Since the code above deals with selecting AND cropping within the same Intent, it is unknown to me how I could possibly store the selected file URI **BEFORE** selecting it through this Intent. This is actually why I posted this question in the first place.

Comment: Load bitmap from uri and set Parcelable Bitmap in "data" extra.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. When  startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA); is called, the OS takes over, there's no way in getting the URI before that line returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found out that it's bad practice to rely on this intent, since it might be removed or changed in future versions of the Android OS.
Guess that's why it was so hard to find any real information about it in the first place.
Anyway, I ended up using a custom crop library instead of relying on the internal android intent.

Comment: which library are you using ?

Comment: I had a good reading on The CommonsBlog (owner is very active here on Stackoverflow), that's where i found out about the problems behind using the integrated crop functionality, why it's better to use custom libraries and it's where I found a few links to custom libraries. Right now I'm using this [library](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage) and this is the [blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) I'm talking about, there you can find other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the links, can I ask why you chose that library from other 4 ? If there is some reason, it could save some of my time :)

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I took a quick look at the documentation of a few of those libs and went with the one that seemed the most basic and stable one, I didn't have much time to test all of them. Until now I didn't have any issues with the one I'm using.

Comment: I lost a day trying to make the crop intent work (because it worked with the default gallery, but not with the Google Photo app) and now I find that blog. Thanks @r41n